How to understand sum of random numbers of random variables
Suppose $(\Omega,F, P)$ is a probability space and $X_i$ are r.v. taking values in $\Bbb{R}$ defined on it. $T$ is another r.v. defined on it with values in $\Bbb{N}$.
I encountered so many expressions as $f=\sum _{1}^{T} X_i$ in stochastic process and used to understand it as a r.v. defined on $(\Omega,F, P)$ and its evaluation at a point is $f(w)= \sum _{1}^{T(w)} X_i(w)$ which makes sense. However, it is very tempting to view it as a composition of two functions, one is $g(k) = \sum _{1}^{k} X_i$, and $T$. Is $g$ a measurable function? What is the domain of $g$? Specifically, $g$ is $\Bbb{N}$/ ?? measurable ?

You have the function $g(k,\omega):=\sum_{i=1}^k X_i(\omega)$, which maps $\Bbb N\times\Omega$ to $\Bbb R$, and is product measurable. You also have the map $\phi:\Omega\to\Bbb N\times\Omega$ defined by $\phi(\omega) =(T(\omega),\omega)$.  This is also measurable. Your random sum is the composition $g\circ\phi$, which is then measurable, so a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$.

The measurability of $g$ and $\phi$ are guaranteed by definition?

They meet to be checked, but it’s straightforward.
